# Parsing XML with selectors in IE8-

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, sizzle

I am currently parsing through a WMS Capabilities XML file using selectors and this works great, nice clean code solution.

However I have stumbled across an issue with IE8- (Chrome, Safari, Firefox etc all working perfectly)

```
$.get(capabilitiesUrl, function (data) {
  $("WMT_MS_Capabilities Capability Layer Layer Name",  $(data)).not("Style Name").each(function (i) {
    layerNames[i] = $(this).text();
  });
});
```

This will successfully populate my array of `layerNames` in the decent browsers.

In IE9+ `data` is type of `[Object, Document]`

However in IE8- the type of `data` is a type of `IXMLDOMDocument2` which I can't parse with the selector query.

The `IXMLDOMDocument2` is also read only causing sizzle to throw an exception on:

`outerCache = elem[ expando ] || (elem[ expando ] = {});`

as it will try to run through `elem[ expando ] = {}` which fails as the `IXMLDOMDocument2` is read only. With a `Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

---

Is there a way for me to populate my `layerNames` array using selectors or am I chasing the impossible?

Comment: This is starnge... If you comment out your current code inside the success callback and add `console.log($(data).find("WMT_MS_Capabilities"))`, do you still get an error?

Comment: No it doesn't cause an error with just `$(data).find("WMT_MS_Capabilities")` I believe it is the `.not()` causing the error to throw in sizzle.

Comment: Well doing a `$(data).find("WMT_MS_Capabilities Capability Layer Layer Name").each(..` works in IE8. However if I add the `.not("Style Name")` IE8- will throw the sizzle issue as I expected.

Comment: can you possibly post your XML? and what is the version of jQuery you use?

Comment: Found the solution to this but `jQuery v1.9.1` and an XML is just a WMS Capabilities that is written to spec, bit too large to share easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out.

If you use the `.find()` instead of the `find in` method it will parse properly in IE8-

Then I still had the issue of the `.not()` causing the exception in `sizzle`.

I solved this by instead of using the `jQuery` API of `.not()` to using the `:not()` selector.

---

**The solution is as follows:**

```
$(data).find("WMT_MS_Capabilities Capability Layer Layer Name:not(Style Name)").each(function (i) {
  layerNames[i] = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: excellent! great work in finding a solution. Sorry, I had to step out - it's work time here - Monday morning. :)

Comment: also, are you able to accept this answer and close the question? this will definitely benefit other users.